# Is there a way where i can find the missing numbers from 1 table to another table? (Comparison)

Tags: mysql, excel

is there a query where I can compare 2  table datas? For example.

My first table has ID 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. My 2nd table has ID 1,3,5,7,9.

My target is to get the missing values. So my expected output is 2,4,6,8,10.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    num
FROM
    first_table t1 
WHERE
    num 
NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
        num 
     FROM 
        second_table
    );
```